# Scenekit: Why SCNNode should not be subclassed?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I keep reading in StackOverflow that we shouldnt subclass SCNNode, can someone please point me in the right direction for Scenekit best practices ?

I feel that subclassing a SCNNode will help me having special methods different types of subclasses. Following Object Oriented Programming.. maybe a 3d Car which is a subclass of SCNNode could have methods for starting the engine, moving, opening the doors, etc..

If that is not the right way.. how can be couple SCNNodes to extra properties and methods? And also, how can be distinguish SCNNodes that are cars, against SCNNodes that are trucks or AirPlanes or anything else ?

Comment: There are a few **absurd, very old** comments on SO that you "shouldn't subclass SCNNode".  It is an utterly absurd comment. OF COURSE you should subclass SCNNode!  It's how you program anything in 3D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally don't see anything wrong with subclassing `SCNNode`, depending of course on why you need to do so.

A key consideration here is the following:

> If you are adding general purpose functionalities that should be
>   available to every SCNNode, then make an extension.
>
> All SCNNode instances can then call these new methods.

On the other hand:

> If you are adding functionality that should be restricted to special
>   instances of SCNNode, and you need to identify these specifically: then 
>   make a subclass, since only instances of these can use your new
>   methods.

If you chose to use an extension of `SCNNode`, this would mean that any functions that your create could be applied to any `SCNNode`.

Let's say for example therefore, that you wanted allow any `SCNNode` to grow and shrink then an `extension` would be your best bet e.g:

```
extension SCNNode{

    /// Doubles The Size Of The SCNNode & Then Returns It To Its Original Size
    func growAndShrink(){

        //1. Create An SCNAction Which Will Double The Size Of Our Node
        let growAction = SCNAction.scale(by: 2, duration: 5)

        //2. Create Another SCNAction Wjich Will Revert Our Node Back To It's Original Size
        let shrinkAction = SCNAction.scale(by: 0.5, duration: 5)

        //3. Create An Animation Sequence Which Will Store Our Actions
        let animationSequence = SCNAction.sequence([growAction, shrinkAction])

        //4. Run The Sequence
        self.runAction(animationSequence)

    }

}
```

However, if you wanted for example to create an `SCNNode` which had functions which would only be available to that instance, then creating a `subclass` may be the way forward.

Let's say then that we needed to create an `SCNNode` with an `SCNPlaneGeometry` that provided us specific information about that Node, then we might create a subclass like so:

```
class PlaneNode: SCNNode {

    let DEFAULT_IMAGE: String = "defaultGrid"
    let NAME: String = "PlaneNode"
    var planeGeometry: SCNPlane
    var planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor

    var widthInfo: String!
    var heightInfo: String!
    var alignmentInfo: String!

    //---------------
    //MARK: LifeCycle
    //---------------

    /// Inititialization
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    ///   - node: SCNNode
    ///   - node: Bool
    init(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, node: SCNNode, image: Bool, identifier: Int, opacity: CGFloat = 0.25){

        //1. Create The SCNPlaneGeometry
        self.planeAnchor = anchor
        self.planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)

        super.init()

        //2. If The Image Bool Is True We Use The Default Image From The Assets Bundle
        let planeMaterial = SCNMaterial()

        if image{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: DEFAULT_IMAGE)

        }else{

            planeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
        }

        //3. Set The Geometries Contents
        self.planeGeometry.materials = [planeMaterial]

        //4. Set The Position Of The PlaneNode
        planeNode.simdPosition = float3(self.planeAnchor.center.x, 0, self.planeAnchor.center.z)

        //5. Rotate It On It's XAxis
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        //6. Set The Opacity Of The Node
        planeNode.opacity = opacity

        //7. Add The PlaneNode
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //8. Set The Nodes ID
        node.name = "\(NAME) \(identifier)"

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }


    /// Updates The Size Of The Plane As & When The ARPlaneAnchor Has Been Updated
    ///
    /// - Parameter anchor: ARPlaneAnchor
    func update(_ anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

        self.planeAnchor = anchor

        self.planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
        self.planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

        self.position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0.01, anchor.center.z)

        returnPlaneInfo()
    }

    //-----------------------
    //MARK: Plane Information
    //-----------------------

    /// Returns The Size Of The ARPlaneAnchor & Its Alignment
    func returnPlaneInfo(){

        let widthOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.x
        let heightOfPlane = self.planeAnchor.extent.z

        var planeAlignment: String!

        switch planeAnchor.alignment {

        case .horizontal:
            planeAlignment = "Horizontal"
        case .vertical:
            planeAlignment = "Vertical"
        }

        #if DEBUG
        print("""
            Width Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane))
            Height Of Plane =  \(String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane))
            Plane Alignment = \(planeAlignment)
            """)
        #endif

        self.widthInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", widthOfPlane)
        self.heightInfo = String(format: "%.2fm", heightOfPlane)
        self.alignmentInfo = planeAlignment
    }

}
```

It seems, in your case, that since you plan to have very specific instances e.g. trucks, airplanes etc, each with their own specific functions, then  using an `SCNNode` subclass could be the way forward.

Hope it helps...

**Update:** As per you request e.g. How would this work in the case of using an `.scn file`?

Some `pseudo code` might look like so:

```
/// Creates & Manages The Car Model
class Car: SCNNode {

    let MODEL_SCALE = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    let MODEL_POSITION = SCNVector3(1, 0, -2.5)
    let MODEL_ROTATION: CGFloat = 30.45
    let TURN_DURATION: Double = 1

    var leftFrontWheel: SCNNode!
    var rightFrontWheel: SCNNode!
    var leftBackWheel: SCNNode!
    var rightBackWheel: SCNNode!

    //--------------------
    //MARK: Initialization
    //--------------------

    override init() {

        super.init()

        //1. Get The Car Model From The Assetts Bundle
        guard let carModel = SCNScene(named: "StackOverflow.scnassets/Models/Car.scn"),
            let modelNode = carModel.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Root", recursively: false),
            let frontLeftWheel = modelNode.childNode(withName: "leftFront", recursively: false),
            let frontRightWheel = modelNode.childNode(withName: "rightFront", recursively: false),
            let rearLeftWheel = modelNode.childNode(withName: "leftRear", recursively: false),
            let rearRightWheel = modelNode.childNode(withName: "rightRear", recursively: false) else { return }


        //2. Scale, Rotate & Position The Car
        self.scale = MODEL_SCALE
        self.simdRotation = simd_float4 (0, 1, 0, Float(MODEL_ROTATION.degreesToRadians))
        self.position = MODEL_POSITION

        //2. Create A Reference To Each Wheel
        self.leftFrontWheel = frontLeftWheel
        self.rightFrontWheel = frontRightWheel
        self.leftBackWheel = rearLeftWheel
        self.rightBackWheel = rearRightWheel


        //3. Add The Car To The Root Node
        self.addChildNode(modelNode)

        print("""
            Loaded Car Model
            Scale = \(MODEL_SCALE)
            Rotation = \(MODEL_ROTATION)
            Position = \(MODEL_POSITION)
            """)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented") }

    //---------------
    //MARK: Animation
    //---------------

    /// Runs The Wheel Animation
    func animateWheels(){

        let wheelTurnAnimationOut = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle:  SCNVector4(0 , 0 , 1, CGFloat(45).degreesToRadians), duration: TURN_DURATION)
        let wheelTurnAnimationIn = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle:  SCNVector4(0 , 0 , 1, CGFloat(0).degreesToRadians), duration: TURN_DURATION)
        let turningSequence = SCNAction.sequence([wheelTurnAnimationOut, wheelTurnAnimationIn])
        let turningAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(turningSequence)
        leftFrontWheel.runAction(turningAction)
        rightFrontWheel.runAction(turningAction)
        leftBackWheel.runAction(turningAction)
        rightBackWheel.runAction(turningAction)

    }

}
```

Which you could then initialise and manage the functions like so:

```
 let car = Car()
 self.augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(car)
 car.animateWheels()
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I see.. how would this work if the SCNNode comes from a .scn file ?

Comment:  very interesting this helps a lot. Thanks for such a complete answer

Comment: For some reason, the standard `init` seems to have been removed from SCNNode meaning that it now has no designated initialisers suitable for use in subclasses.... *edit* or at least it fails to work in some circumstances....

Comment: @Ash, mmm, I just created a quick test in Xcode 10.2 and seems to be working fine :)  What version are you using?

Comment: The issue seems to be only occasional and I've not been able to replicate it. Really annoying.

Comment: The init() is working perfectly in SCNNode.

Answer (score 4):

### It is absolutely, completely, normal to subclass SCNNode.

I've literally *never seen* a "plain" SCNNode used in any project. What would you do with it?

#### There are about five comments on S.O. that say "you shouldn't subclass SCNNode". These five comments are totally wrong.

Apple mention in a document that you can't subclass the SCN ***scene*** ...

#### This internet myth appears to have been started by a typo:

It seems that in the early days of scene kit, **a writer on the apple developer site, in a post about SCNScene, made a typo and wrote "you cannot subclass a node" while they were in the middle of typing about how it's not possible to subclass a scene**.

This was copied two or three times by people trying to write answers on different forums including SO.

Anyone can give a zillion examples of subclassing a node:

```
///Node that shows a picture
public class PictureNode: SCNNode {
    
    ///Set the image shown on this PictureNode.
    public func setToImage(named: String) {
        geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: named)
    }
    
    public func setToPlaceholderImage() { ...
    
    public func showWarningLabel() { ...
    
    public func animateToBlack() { ...
    
    public func reshapeNow(toAspectRatio: CGFloat) {
        thePlane.width = toAspectRatio
        thePlane.height = 1.0
    }
    
    private var pl = SCNPlane()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        pl.widthSegmentCount = 1
        pl... etc
        geometry = thePlane
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

{As an aside, if you want to "subclass" scene, you subclass `SCNView`, which is what you do in every scene kit project.}