# How to attach a struct or class object to a SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I'm trying to create a scene where different users can display different cars. When the user first signs into the app they get uid, username etc. When they choose a car the car model has the type of car and a user object that identifies them.

I can create a car and implement the hitTest to find which car was tapped. What I can't figure out is how do I assign a data model to the car that was tapped so that I know who's who?

The only property I found on the node so far is the `node.name`, I can attach the userId to it and just go through an array of users to find out who's who but that doesn;t seem practical if I have a lot of users. I also need that property when removing a node:

```
sceneView.session.pause()
sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
    // this would actually remove all the ferraries on the scene but this is just an example
    if node.name == "ferrari" {
        node.removeFromParentNode()
    }
}
```

**How can I attach a data model to a SCNNode?**

```
class User {
    var userId: String?
    var username: String?
}

class RaceCar {
    var user: User?
    var type: String?
}

// user creates an account and picks a ferrari

let raceCar = RaceCar()
let type = raceCar.type!

switch type {

    case "ferrari":

        createFerrariAndAddItToScene(raceCar)

    case "bmw":
    ...etc
}

func createFerrariAndAddItToScene(_ raceCar: RaceCar) {

      let image = art.scnassests/"\(raceCar.typ!e).jpg"

      let material = SCNMaterial()
      material.diffuse.contents = image

      let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.1, height: 0.1)
      plane.materials = [material]

      let node = SCNNode()
      node.name = raceCar.type!
      node.geometry = plane
      node.position = SCNVector(0.0, 0.0, -0.2)

      sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}

@objc func nodeWasTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let sceneView = sender.view as? ARSCNView else { return }  
    let touchLocation = sender.location(in: sceneView)

    let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: [:])

    if !hitResults.isEmpty {

        guard let hitResult = hitResults.first  else { return }  
        let node = hitResult.node

        print(node.name) // I need to get some info from the dataModel here like node.raceCar.user.username or node.raceCar.user.userId
    }
}
```

Comment: You just subclass SCNNode, which is the basis of making scene kit projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `SCNNode` and add any data model you need to it:

```
class CarNode: SCNNode {
  var raceCar: RaceCar?

  init(raceCar: RaceCar, geometry: SCNGeometry) {
    super.init()

    self.geometry = geometry

    self.raceCar = raceCar
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

To create new node simply use this new class:

```
func createFerrariAndAddItToScene(_ raceCar: RaceCar) {
  ...
  let node = CarNode(raceCar: raceCar, geometry: plane)
  ...
}
```

To access your data model you can do like so:

```
@objc func nodeWasTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  ...
  if let node = hitResult.node as? CarNode {
    print(node.raceCar.user.username)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I just read 4 posts that said not to subclass SCNNode. I'll try and find the links and send them to you

Comment: @LanceSamaria No problem. I don't think subclassing SCNNode would cause any problem since you're only adding some properties. I've done and seen this in many projects.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I'm a littler tired but as I looked through the answers they were mainly talking about SCNScene. There were a few mentions of scnnodes but they were talking about functionality which I'm not changing. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question if you have the time. I notice that your answer has the geometry as an argument in the initializer. Is that necessary for it to work or just for cleaner code?

Comment: @LanceSamaria No. You can also set geometry after you create a new instance but this way you will be forced to provide a geometry in case you might forget it somewhere. It's optional :]

Comment: Oh ok, I just saw 2 other answers somewhere else and they had geometry in the init so I wasn't sure. This was very helpful. Enjoy your weekend, Cheers friend!

Comment: @LanceSamaria and for anyone googling here it is ABSOLUTELY, YES, the case that you subclass SCNNode.  I've literally never seen one not subclassed. The bizarre "internet myth" that you shouldn't subclass a node has been resolved and is explained here: it was due to a typo, which then spread to 2 or 3 other posts, and become an internet myth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407576/294884

Answer (score 1):

I had some luck using setValue:ForKey:

```
node.setValue(tile, forKey: "tile")

...

if let tile = node.value(forKey: "tile") as? Tile {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Totally the best answer.